# How to delete my Imgur account?

Tags: account-management, imgur

Browsing around [Imgur](http://imgur.com/), I can't find a way to get rid of my account.

Comment: I even went as far as creating an account to check myself. I can't find one either. Have you tried the contact us form?

Comment: Surely that functionality is too basic to ask support for? But seriously, I just thought there was a 'hidden' way that someone here would know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Terms of Service](https://imgur.com/tos) say, "Don't upload copyrighted material, harassment, spam, gore, pornography, or especially child pornography. If you do, we will ban you, delete all your images, report you to the authorities if necessary, and prevent you from viewing any images hosted on Imgur.com."

So, I suppose you could try uploading some gore?

[image]

*Seriously*, though, just use the [contact form](https://imgur.com/contact) and request deletion. I'm sure they get them all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your account in the right hand corner

Find the setting and click on it

Near the bottom towards the right there is some linked text that says "Delete my account"

Simple click on it hit the checkboxes that show and delete both your account and all of your images.

[Imgur support page](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/203889395-Delete-an-Account)

[image]

[image]